# scss - setting parent doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, sass

I have the following code:

```
 <div class="input-group want-outline">
        <input class="form-control no-outline @(IsValid ? "" : "is-invalid")"
               type="text"......
```

and this is my scss:

```
.no-outline:focus {
    box-shadow: none;

    &.want-outline {
        border-radius: 2.5rem;
        border-color: #80bdff;
        border-width: 0.2rem;
    }
}
```

when the input receives focus, it correctly sets box-shadow to none, but doesn't apply the border details to the parent. ive also tried:

```
 & { border-radius.....
```

and

```
 > & { border-radius.....
```

to reference the parent, these dont work either.

Comment: @Huangism so if I remove all references to the class 'want-outline'  Remove it from div element and use `& {....` it compiles to `.no-outline:focus {
  box-shadow: none; }
  .no-outline:focus {
    border-radius: 2.5rem;
    border-color: #80bdff;
    border-width: 0.2rem; }` and still doesn't give me my desired result

Comment: oh wait, sorry what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to target the parent based on the child behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @Huangism , I've tried that and it gives the selector as per your suggestion, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @bilpor sorry I misread the html, it looks like you are trying to select the parent based on a child condition which is currently impossible to do with css

Comment: @Huangism Scss is supposed to support this kind of behavior

Comment: @bilpor SCSS converts to CSS. You cannot change parent styles based on child selection.

Comment: @bilpor you are misreading how scss works, it's just a preprocesser of css. The output is css so if css does not support parent selector, it is not possible for scss to support it. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector look at the generated css on the right side, none of those selects a parent based on a child. They should rename this instead of saying parent selector, it's confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the border on the **focus-within** style property which will apply styles to the parent element when the focus is within it (ie - when the input within it has focus.. **The following uses straight css but can easily be converted to scss.**

Note that IE does not support this style property at all (https://caniuse.com/?search=focus-within) but really who cares about ie? :)

Also - your border problem might be because you are not setting the border type (eg " solid / dashed / dotted) - i tend to set all the border styles in the shorthand version most of the time.

```css
.no-outline:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

  .want-outline {
      padding: 16px;
      border-radius: 2.5rem;
      display: inline-block;
      border: solid 0.2rem transparent;
  }
  
  .want-outline:focus-within {
     border-color: #80bdff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="input-group want-outline">
   <input class="form-control no-outline" type="text" placeholde="enter txt"/>
<div>
```